# API Automation using selenium Rest Assured

Tags: java

I am automating API services using rest assured in `selenium java`. Now I am facing a scenario where my API request returns Excel response ( if I extract the response as `Response.body.asString()`: it returns box characters). Could someone please help me with this?

Comment: Please provide your code? Have you tried to use byte array?

Comment: Excel files are not text, but binary, so you have to use byte array and e.g. the ByteArrayInputStream together with a library like Apache POI if you want to get an Excel object out of your response.